# Perform a post using netty4 component in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I want to perform a post using netty4 in camel but its returning bad request 400, i have tried many permutations of http options to see if any work but the result is same (as consumer its working but as producer its not)

@Component
public class RestDslRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
    .component("netty4-http")
    .host("localhost").port("8686")
    .enableCORS(true)
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")
   .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

    rest("/api")
    .get("/")
        .to("bean:helloBean")
    .post().type(PostRequestType.class)
        .to("bean:postBean");

    /*from("netty4-http:http://localhost:8686/foo")
  .transform().constant("Bye World");
  */

from("netty4-http:http://localhost:8686/foo")
  .log("Logged id issue without body: ${header.id}")
 .to("netty4-http:http://ptsv2.com/t/8wl8p-1547734804/post?bridgeEndpoint=true");


}
```